# Prevent GitHub app to be installed on personnal GitHub accounts

Tags: github, octokit, github-app

I'm the owner of a GitHub app. I would like this app to only be installed on Organization account and not on personnal GitHub accounts. The reason is that our app doesn't make sense and doesn't work for personnal accounts.

Is there any GitHub settings to not allow installation on personnal accounts?

Thank you!

[image: GitHub app for organization only]

Comment: Pinging. I am also looking if there is a way to accomplish this